# spring boot oauth ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : NestedServletException: nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError]

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-oauth2

i created a authorization with spring boot oauth 2. I cannot get an access token with the data from database.

My AuthorizationServer:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    @Autowired
    private PropertyConfiguration propertyConfiguration;

    @Override
    public void configure(final AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
        oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
                .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }
    @Override
    public void configure(final ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
                .withClient(propertyConfiguration.getPasswordId())
                .secret(passwordEncoder.encode(propertyConfiguration.getPasswordSecret()))
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password")
                .scopes(SCOPE_WRITE)
                .autoApprove(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints
                .tokenStore(tokenStore())
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new InMemoryTokenStore();
    }
```

My Main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.kazi.core.entities")
public class OAuthApplication {

    @Bean
    public UserServiceImpl userServiceImpl() {
        return new UserServiceImpl();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(OAuthApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

My CustomerUserDetails:

```
@Configuration("customUserDetailsService")
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {


    private UserServiceImpl userServiceImpl;

    @Autowired
    public CustomUserDetailsService(UserServiceImpl userServiceImpl) {
        this.userServiceImpl = userServiceImpl;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        final User user = userServiceImpl.findByUsername(username);
        if (user == null)
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(String.format("User %s does not exist!", username));
        return new UserRepositoryUserDetails(user);
    }

    private final static class UserRepositoryUserDetails extends User implements UserDetails {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private UserRepositoryUserDetails(User user) {
            super(user);
        }

        @Override
        public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
            return getRoles();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
            return !super.isBlocked();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

My SecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.parentAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean())
                .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("emoleumassi")
                .password(passwordEncoder().encode("today"))
                .roles("USER");
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

It works fine when i set the credentials directly in code, i get an access token. But if i use the CustomUserService like this:

```
    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.parentAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean())
                .userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
```

The console repeats many times, may be 20 times:

```
Hibernate: select user0_.user_id as user_id1_5_, user0_.blocked as blocked2_5_, user0_.description as descript3_5_, user0_.email as email4_5_, user0_.enabled as enabled5_5_, user0_.first_login as first_lo6_5_, user0_.first_name as first_na7_5_, user0_.last_login as last_log8_5_, user0_.last_name as last_nam9_5_, user0_.password as passwor10_5_, user0_.username as usernam11_5_ from user user0_ where user0_.username=?
Hibernate: select threads0_.user_id as user_id1_8_0_, threads0_.thread_id as thread_i2_8_0_, thread1_.thread_id as thread_i1_4_1_ from user_thread threads0_ inner join thread thread1_ on threads0_.thread_id=thread1_.thread_id where threads0_.user_id=?
Hibernate: select roles0_.user_id as user_id1_7_0_, roles0_.role_id as role_id2_7_0_, role1_.role_id as role_id1_3_1_, role1_.name as name2_3_1_ from user_role roles0_ inner join role role1_ on roles0_.role_id=role1_.role_id where roles0_.user_id=?
Hibernate: select users0_.role_id as role_id2_7_0_, users0_.user_id as user_id1_7_0_, user1_.user_id as user_id1_5_1_, user1_.blocked as blocked2_5_1_, user1_.description as descript3_5_1_, user1_.email as email4_5_1_, user1_.enabled as enabled5_5_1_, user1_.first_login as first_lo6_5_1_, user1_.first_name as first_na7_5_1_, user1_.last_login as last_log8_5_1_, user1_.last_name as last_nam9_5_1_, user1_.password as passwor10_5_1_, user1_.username as usernam11_5_1_ from user_role users0_ inner join user user1_ on users0_.user_id=user1_.user_id where users0_.role_id=?
Hibernate: select users0_.role_id as role_id2_7_0_, users0_.user_id as user_id1_7_0_, user1_.user_id as user_id1_5_1_, user1_.blocked as blocked2_5_1_, user1_.description as descript3_5_1_, user1_.email as email4_5_1_, user1_.enabled as enabled5_5_1_, user1_.first_login as first_lo6_5_1_, user1_.first_name as first_na7_5_1_, user1_.last_login as last_log8_5_1_, user1_.last_name as last_nam9_5_1_, user1_.password as passwor10_5_1_, user1_.username as usernam11_5_1_ from user_role users0_ inner join user user1_ on users0_.user_id=user1_.user_id where users0_.role_id=?
Hibernate: select users0_.role_id as role_id2_7_0_, users0_.user_id as user_id1_7_0_, user1_.user_id as user_id1_5_1_, user1_.blocked as blocked2_5_1_, user1_.description as descript3_5_1_, user1_.email as email4_5_1_, user1_.enabled as enabled5_5_1_, user1_.first_login as first_lo6_5_1_, user1_.first_name as first_na7_5_1_, user1_.last_login as last_log8_5_1_, user1_.last_name as last_nam9_5_1_, user1_.password as passwor10_5_1_, user1_.username as usernam11_5_1_ from user_role users0_ inner join user user1_ on users0_.user_id=user1_.user_id where users0_.role_id=?
Hibernate: select jobs0_.user_id as user_id1_6_0_, jobs0_.job_id as job_id2_6_0_, job1_.job_id as job_id1_0_1_, job1_.category as category2_0_1_, job1_.creation_date as creation3_0_1_, job1_.description as descript4_0_1_, job1_.location as location5_0_1_, job1_.salary as salary6_0_1_, job1_.status as status7_0_1_, job1_.title as title8_0_1_ from user_job jobs0_ inner join job job1_ on jobs0_.job_id=job1_.job_id where jobs0_.user_id=?
```

and i get this exception:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1055) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:203) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:108) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1591) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
```

When i removed this line `auth.parentAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean())` i get

```
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "Bad credentials"
}
```

My User entity:

```
@Table
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private int userId;

    @Column(unique = true, columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(50)", nullable = false)
    private String username;

    @Column(unique = true, columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(50)", nullable = false)
    private String email;

    @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "BIT")
    private boolean enabled;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(50)", nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(20)", nullable = false)
    private String firstLogin;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(20)")
    private String lastLogin;

    @Column(unique = true, columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(50)")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(unique = true, columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(50)")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "BIT")
    private boolean blocked;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String description;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_job",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "job_id"))
    private Set<Job> jobs = new HashSet<>();

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_thread",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "thread_id"))
    private Set<Thread> threads = new HashSet<>();

    public User() { }

    public User(User user) {
        super();
        this.userId = user.getUserId();
        this.roles = user.getRoles();
        this.username = user.getUsername();
        this.email = user.getEmail();
        this.enabled = user.isEnabled();
        this.blocked = user.isBlocked();
        this.password = user.getPassword();
    }
    // getter, setter
```

My curl request

```
curl -i -v -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -k http://localhost:8080/oauth/token -H 'Authorization: Basic Y2xpZW50OnNlY3JldA==' -d 'grant_type=password&client_id=client&user=emoleumassi&password=today&scope=write'
```

This user exists in the DB with the role User.

I use the `spring-security-oauth2` version `2.3.5.RELEASE` and boot parent starter `2.2.2.RELEASE`

Comment: This NestedServletException is got deprecated since @Deprecated(since="6.0"), is there any replacement for this ? Its not required now ?

Answer (score 0):

First, I changed

```
 @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.parentAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean())
                .userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
```

to

```
 @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.
                .userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
```

Second, I encrypted the password in the Database `today` -> `$2a$04$TwPX14ddISSYsW4/fvzxfu8uSyJQXq415OrlWwrLACxBycRmdS07u`

I made my `curl` request with no encrypted password:

```
curl -i -v -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -k http://localhost:8080/oauth/token -H 'Authorization: Basic Y2xpZW50OnNlY3JldA==' -d 'grant_type=password&client_id=client&username=emoleumassi&password=today&scope=write'
```

Does someone know the influence of `parentAuthenticationManager`?

Comment: did the changes you describe result in a successful curl request?

Comment: @AlessandroScarlatti yes